# How to get currentPagePath in Slingservlet?

Tags: aem

From some javascript I call the following `Slingservlet` with `("/bin/fooServlet?"+params);`

```java
@SlingServlet(paths = "/bin/fooServlet", methods = "GET", metatype = true)
public class FooServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {    
..
protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) {
        Session  session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
        Page currentPage = pageManager.getPage(request.getPathInfo());
         String currentPagePath = currentPage.getPath();
...
}
```

My Question is: How to get the `currentPagePath` of the current Page in `FooServlet`? `currentPagePath` in the code is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Thomas mentioned, if you define a servlet with fixed paths property, you wouldn't have reference to a Resource.

One way of achieving this is by passing your page path along with the request to the servlet. Also `CQ.WCM.getPagePath()` returns only `/libs/wcm/core/content/siteadmin`, as the current page is siteadmin and you may need to tweak your script a bit in order to access the selected page within siteadmin.

To get your page path either from siteadmin or from the page itself, you can use the following script and then pass the value to your servlet for further processing.

```js
    var currentPagePath = null;
    /* if accessed via siteadmin */
    if(CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.hasListSelection()) {
        var grid = CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.getActiveGrid();
        var selections = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelections();

        /*Assuming that you are selecting only one page at a time. */
        currentPagePath = selections[0].id;
    } else { /* accessed via page */
        currentPagePath = CQ.WCM.getPagePath();
    }
```

And then you can call the servlet with the currentPagePath as one of the parameters.

```
GET /bin/fooServlet?currentPagePath=' + currentPagePath + '&foo=bar';
```

**UPDATE**
The above code works fine for CQ 5.5 + , for older versions you can use this.

```js
    var currentPagePath = null;
    /* if accessed via siteadmin */
    if(CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.hasListSelection()) {
        var grid = CQ.Ext.getCmp(window.CQ_SiteAdmin_id + "-grid");
        if (grid) {
            var selections = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelections();
            currentPagePath = selections[0].id;
        }
    } else { /* accessed via page */
        currentPagePath = CQ.WCM.getPagePath();
    }
```

Comment: I allready found this code and tested it but have the following Error in the line var grid = CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.getActiveGrid(); : <exception>TypeError: CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.getActiveGrid is not a function. Bye the way I have cq5.4

Comment: You didn't mention that in the question. Anyways, i have updated the code for the same. You can check with that now.

Answer (score 2):

If you define the servlet with a fixed `paths` property you don't have any reference to a `Resource` or `Page`
You either need to define `resourceTypes` that matches to a page component or use `cq:Page`, but this will then be active for every request to a page and is not recommended without at least some `selectors`
Then you can get the `Resource` with `request.getResource()`. To get a `Page` you'll need to adapt the `ResourceResolver` to a [PageManager](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/PageManager.html) and use `getContainingPage(Resource resource)`.

Have a look at the documentation:
http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html

Comment: I need the path to the current page not the path to the servlet

Comment: what do you mean with current page. The page where the JavaScript is executed? Another option would be a query parameter containing the current page path which you can get by request.getParameter() and then again you can use the mentioned PageManager method

Comment: current page is the page where the javaScript is executed. what I tried is to set currentpagepath in the javascript with CQ.WCM.getPagePath(). This works fine but the Problem is, when I call the page from the siteadmin, CQ.WCM.getPagePath() deliver the path of the siteadmin (/libs/wcm/core/content/siteadmin). Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

`request.getPathInfo()` in this case presumably is `/bin/fooServlet?[parameterString]`, which is why PageManager is returning null for its path — from the PageManager's point of view, no resource exists at this location.

One simple option would be to send an additional callingPage parameter when hitting the Servlet. This way you could just read it from the parameter map:

```
GET /bin/fooServlet?foo=bar&callingPage=/en/home.html

void doGet() {
    PageManager pageManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(PageManager.class);    
    String callingPage = request.getParameter("callingPage");
    String callingPagePath = pageManager.getPage(callingPage).getPath();
}
```

Comment: ok I can get callingPage in the javascript by CQ.WCM.getPagePath() but this doen't work, when I access the page from the siteadmin as mentioned in my commet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's a good pratice, but perhaps you could use the referer.

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

try {
    String currentPagePath = new URI(request.getHeader("referer")).getPath();
} catch (java.net.URISyntaxException e) {
}
```