# AEM: how to pass current page path from jsp to dialog

Tags: content-management-system, aem

I have a country selection drop-down which I am populating from a servlet using a selector:

Currently I am passing the locale as a request parameter.

```
options="/bin/services/dropdownservlet.GET_DROPDOWN_VALUES.json?locale=$PATH"
```

Now I want to pass a locale as another selector. For this I am thinking of an approach to get the `currentPage.path` from the jsp to dialog and pass it as a 2nd selector. How can I do that ?

```
options="/bin/services/dropdownservlet.GET_DROPDOWN_VALUES.CURRENTPATH"
```

Is there a way that I should be able to get the page path in my servlet as a string which I can use to trigger the servlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are ways to get the page page, both client side or server side:

**JavaScript:**

```
var currentPagePath = null;
/* if accessed via siteadmin */
if(CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.hasListSelection()) {
    var grid = CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.getActiveGrid();
    var selections = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelections();

    /*Assuming that you are selecting only one page at a time. */
    currentPagePath = selections[0].id;
} else { /* accessed via page */
    currentPagePath = CQ.WCM.getPagePath();
}
```

**Java:**

```
PageManager pageManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(PageManager.class);    
String callingPage = request.getParameter("callingPage");
String callingPagePath = pageManager.getPage(callingPage).getPath();
```

See [How to get currentPagePath in Slingservlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738460/how-to-get-currentpagepath-in-slingservlet)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your servlet returns JSON such as:

```
[{"text" : "first option", "value" : "alpha"}, {"text" : "second option", "value" : "bravo"}]
```

You can use the optionsProvider to run a JavaScript function where you can dynamically setup your request:

```
<product
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    name="./product"
    fieldLabel="Product"
    type="select"
    xtype="selection"
    optionsProvider="function() {
        var selectors = ['GET_DROPDOWN_VALUES', 'myselector'];
        var url = CQ.shared.HTTP.addSelectors('/bin/services/dropdownservlet.json', selectors);
        return CQ.Util.formatData(CQ.shared.HTTP.eval(CQ.shared.HTTP.noCaching(url)));
    }"/>
```

To answer your question, you can get the current page's path in your optionsProvider function with the following method:

```
CQ.shared.HTTP.getPath()
```

However, I wouldn't use a path as a selector. With the slashes in the page's path, Sling will see the page path as the extension and suffix rather than a selector. I might pass the path in as the suffix or a query param as you're currently doing.

Note, that I wouldn't leave the JavaScript function in your dialog.xml file, but would move it to an external JS file.